# Change http-header of linked files without explicit download script (in an own file)

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers

I want to force the browser to download all files linked inside a RSS-Feed, that is created by a php-script.

Therefore I need to change the HTTP-headers of these files and set

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
```

(and maybe also some other changes).

At the moment I try to do this using a download script, that sets these parameters.

However, the disadvantage of this method is, that I have to link to "download.php" instead of "target.file", which is somehow misleading for the user. Besides, I have to reveal the internal file path to the user or use quite a lot of GET-variables instead.

It would be much better if it was possible to change the HTTP-headers inside the script that generates the RSS-Feed. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the headers from inside the RSS feed. You could, however, hide the `download.php` part with some rewrite magic:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^download/.*$ /download.php?file=$1 [L]
```

This would cause any URL starting with `/download/` to be run through your download script:

- `/img/foo.jpg` - normal file
- `/download/img/foo.jpg` - force a download

You could do a similar thing without the PHP too:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^download/.*$ /$1 [L]

<Location /download>
    Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</Location>
```

Comment: good idea, however I hoped there would be no need to mess around with .htaccess. Thank you